# Trouble with PayPal Adaptive Payments in Node.js

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I cannot for the life of me figure out what's going on.  I'm just trying to do a basic call to PayPal's Adaptive Payments API, the `Pay` call specifically.  I'm trying to achieve this with node.js.  I can make successful calls with `curl`, but node simply refuses to work.  I keep getting a `'Invalid request: {0}'` error message, errorId `580001`.  I've searched for a long time for a solution, and although many people have had seemingly similar issues, their problems were different from mine, and so their solutions haven't worked.

Any help you can offer is **MUCH** appreciated.

Here is the response I keep getting (prettified):

```
{ responseEnvelope: 
   { timestamp: '2012-11-05T03:50:08.216-08:00',
     ack: 'Failure',
     correlationId: 'b1dbb6fea8378',
     build: '4110101' },
  error: 
   [ { errorId: '580001',
       domain: 'PLATFORM',
       subdomain: 'Application',
       severity: 'Error',
       category: 'Application',
       message: 'Invalid request: {0}' } ] }
```

Here's my node code: (Note: I'm using the `request` module: https://github.com/mikeal/request)

```
request = require 'request'

body = JSON.stringify

  actionType: "PAY"
  senderEmail: "happy_1349101075_biz@onehappystudent.com"
  receiverList:
    receiver: [
      email: "luke_1346604373_biz@onehappystudent.com"
      amount: "1.00"
    ]
  currencyCode: "USD"
  feesPayer: "EACHRECEIVER"
  memo: "This is a test"
  cancelUrl: "http://cancelurl"
  returnUrl: "http://returnUrl"
  ipnNotificationUrl: "http://your_ipn_notification_url"
  requestEnvelope:
    errorLanguage: "en_US"

console.log body

console.log request

  url: 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay'

  headers:
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID": "happy_1349101075_biz_api1.onehappystudent.com"
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD": "1349101103"
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE": "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31Avw12OuF33eJo9IbQpXMS6wrOp1."

    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON"
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON"

    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID": "APP-80W284485P519543T"

    "Content-Type": "application/json"

  body: body

, (err, res, bod) ->

  console.log bod
```

Here's the output from running the above code:

```
{"actionType":"PAY","senderEmail":"happy_1349101075_biz@onehappystudent.com","receiverList":{"receiver":[{"email":"luke_1346604373_biz@onehappystudent.com","amount":"1.00"}]},"currencyCode":"USD","feesPayer":"EACHRECEIVER","memo":"This is a test","cancelUrl":"http://cancelurl","returnUrl":"http://returnUrl","ipnNotificationUrl":"http://your_ipn_notification_url","requestEnvelope":{"errorLanguage":"en_US"}}
{ readable: true,
  writable: true,
  headers: 
   { 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID': 'happy_1349101075_biz_api1.onehappystudent.com',
     'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD': '1349101103',
     'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE': 'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31Avw12OuF33eJo9IbQpXMS6wrOp1.',
     'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT': 'JSON',
     'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT': 'JSON',
     'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID': 'APP-80W284485P519543T',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     host: 'svcs.sandbox.paypal.com',
     'content-length': 409 },
  body: <Buffer 7b 22 61 63 74 69 6f 6e 54 79 70 65 22 3a 22 50 41 59 22 2c 22 73 65 6e 64 65 72 45 6d 61 69 6c 22 3a 22 68 61 70 70 79 5f 31 33 34 39 31 30 31 30 37 35 ...>,
  callback: [Function],
  pool: {},
  dests: [],
  __isRequestRequest: true,
  _callback: [Function],
  _events: 
   { error: [Function],
     complete: [Function],
     pipe: { [Function: g] listener: [Function] } },
  uri: 
   { protocol: 'https:',
     slashes: true,
     host: 'svcs.sandbox.paypal.com',
     hostname: 'svcs.sandbox.paypal.com',
     href: 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay',
     pathname: '/AdaptivePayments/Pay',
     path: '/AdaptivePayments/Pay',
     port: 443 },
  _redirectsFollowed: 0,
  maxRedirects: 10,
  followRedirect: true,
  followAllRedirects: false,
  redirects: [],
  setHost: true,
  originalCookieHeader: undefined,
  _jar: undefined,
  port: 443,
  host: 'svcs.sandbox.paypal.com',
  clientErrorHandler: [Function],
  _parserErrorHandler: [Function],
  path: '/AdaptivePayments/Pay',
  httpModule: 
   { Server: { [Function: Server] super_: [Object] },
     createServer: [Function],
     globalAgent: 
      { options: {},
        requests: {},
        sockets: {},
        maxSockets: 5,
        _events: [Object],
        createConnection: [Function: createConnection] },
     Agent: { [Function: Agent] super_: [Object] },
     request: [Function],
     get: [Function] },
  agentClass: 
   { [Function: Agent]
     super_: { [Function: Agent] super_: [Function: EventEmitter], defaultMaxSockets: 5 } },
  agent: 
   { options: {},
     requests: {},
     sockets: {},
     maxSockets: 5,
     _events: { free: [Function] },
     createConnection: [Function: createConnection] } }
{"responseEnvelope":{"timestamp":"2012-11-05T03:50:08.216-08:00","ack":"Failure","correlationId":"b1dbb6fea8378","build":"4110101"},"error":[{"errorId":"580001","domain":"PLATFORM","subdomain":"Application","severity":"Error","category":"Application","message":"Invalid request: {0}"}]}
```

Here's the successful `curl`:

```
curl -s --insecure \
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: happy_1349101075_biz_api1.onehappystudent.com" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: 1349101103" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31Avw12OuF33eJo9IbQpXMS6wrOp1." \
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T" \
-H "host: svcs.sandbox.paypal.com" \
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay -d '{
  "actionType":"PAY",
  "senderEmail":"happy_1349101075_biz@onehappystudent.com",
  "receiverList":{
    "receiver":[{
      "email":"luke_1346604373_biz@onehappystudent.com",
      "amount":"1.00"
    }]
  },
  "currencyCode":"USD",
  "feesPayer":"EACHRECEIVER",
  "memo":"This is a test",
  "cancelUrl":"http://cancelurl",
  "returnUrl":"http://returnUrl",
  "ipnNotificationUrl":"http://your_ipn_notification_url",
  "requestEnvelope":{
    "errorLanguage":"en_US"
  }
}'
```

And here's the response: (prettified for your convenience)

```
{ responseEnvelope: 
   { timestamp: '2012-11-05T03:40:10.613-08:00',
     ack: 'Success',
     correlationId: 'abaf5b13c5515',
     build: '4110101' },
  payKey: 'AP-4B1870921M506553S',
  paymentExecStatus: 'COMPLETED' }
```

Again, any help you can offer is **MUCH** appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh God I feel stupid... I was missing one line...

```
method: 'POST'
```

Lesson learnt - don't code when tired

(unless perhaps you have a large supply of coffee)

Answer (score 4):

not sure if you have pasted your code correct but this code works for me - see if you can find the difference :

```
var request = require('request');
body = JSON.stringify(
  {actionType: "PAY",
  senderEmail: "happy_1349101075_biz@onehappystudent.com",
  receiverList: { receiver:
    [{
      email: "luke_1346604373_biz@onehappystudent.com",
      amount: "1.00"
    }]},
  currencyCode: "USD",
  feesPayer: "EACHRECEIVER",
  memo: "This is a test",
  cancelUrl: "http://cancelurl",
  returnUrl: "http://returnUrl",
  ipnNotificationUrl: "http://your_ipn_notification_url",
  requestEnvelope: {
    errorLanguage: "en_US" }
  })

console.log(body)

request.post({
        headers: {"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID": "happy_1349101075_biz_api1.onehappystudent.com", "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD": "1349101103", "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE": "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31Avw12OuF33eJo9IbQpXMS6wrOp1.", "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON", "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON", "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID": "APP-80W284485P519543T", "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        url: 'https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay',
         body: body
         }, function(error, response, body){
            console.log(body);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Praveen, it does indeed work.  As a result of looking at your example, I located the exact issue with my code, and it's rather embarrassing...